# How to transpile a node_module with webpack in a web worker?

Tags: javascript, webpack, create-react-app, babeljs, babel-loader

I am trying to include a node module ([primitive-ellipsoid](https://github.com/dmnsgn/primitive-ellipsoid)) in my wepback project. The module is not transpiled to es5 so throws an error when used in the browser:

```
Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: /Users/kevzettler/code/crashgiants/node_modules/primitive-ellipsoid/index.js Unexpected token (8:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   // Default to an oblate spheroid
|   const { latSegments = 32, lngSegments = 64, rx = 2, ry = 1, rz = 1 } = {
|     ...options
|   };
|
```

This project is an older `create-react-app` `webpack` that is ejected.

```
    "webpack": "3.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.8.2",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.2.1",
```

It is using `babel` and `babel-loader` and `worker-loader` I have a `webpack.config.dev.js` with rules like:

```
    rules: [
      {
        // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
        // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
        // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
        oneOf: [
          // Process JS with Babel.
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            include: [
              paths.appSrc,
            ],
            exclude: /\.worker.js$/,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
              // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
              // directory for faster rebuilds.
              //cacheDirectory: true,
            },
          },

          {
            test: /\.worker.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
              'worker-loader',
              require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            ]
          }
        ]
```

I have babel configured in package.json with:

```
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy"
    ],
    "presets": [
      [
        "env",
        {
          "targets": "defaults"
        }
      ],
      "flow",
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
```

I have tried messing around with `includes` and `excludes` in the webpack.config.json to no success. I am confused if I need to focus on the `worker-loader` rule because it also uses the `babel-loader` or if the top level `babel-loader` gets applied as well.

UPDATE I only want to transpile the specific `node_module/primitive-ellipsoid` if I transpile the entire `node_modules` there is a bunch of other issues. I have tried

```
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            include: [
              'node_modules/primitive-ellipsoid',
              paths.appSrc,
            ],
            exclude: /\.worker.js$/,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
              // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
              // directory for faster rebuilds.
              //cacheDirectory: true,
            },
          },
```

But this has the same error.

Comment: The `worker-loader` only apply to `.worker.js` file. You can try remove the `include` field from first rule.

Comment: With current setting no rule matches anything in `node_modules` thus the problem.

Comment: Yes, you'll need an exclude that filter `node_modules` but the one used by your worker like this: `exclude: /(clientlib_base)|(node_modules\/(?!(primitive-ellipsoid)/`

Answer (score 0):

Your first rule isn't finding `primitive-ellipsoid`. As mentioned in the comments above, try removing the include from your first build rule:

```
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /\.worker.js$/,
    loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
    options: {
        // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
        // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
        // directory for faster rebuilds.
        //cacheDirectory: true,
    },
},
```

If that doesn't work, try adding another rule that will catch anything else as a fallback and see if it finds your library.

Comment: This solution then attempts to transpile everything in node_modules  which throws other errors. How can I target the specific module???

Comment: Use a regex that only matches that folder, or the JavaScript inside

Comment: have added an update to the question demonstrating a regex on the include that targets the module and still fails to transpile it.